# nodejs request response as unread characters

Tags: node.js, request

Im tring to make a request with nodejs, but Im getting with response those caracters `��!̨=��}�oZdW���Z������ξ�޳��q��~`. When I do the same request in my browser with Jquery it works well and return the correct json. How can I do it with nodejs?

Im using `requestjs` lib to send the post request.

My code:

```
var options = { method: 'POST',
 url: 'myapi',
 headers: 
  { 
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    referer: 'myapirefere',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',
    origin: 'myapiorigin',
    pragma: 'no-cache' },
  body: 'code=123' };

 request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log('body', body)

   });
```

I just added `gzip: true` option and it works!

Comment: Can you post the request code?

Comment: Yes, I just wrote the code

Comment: try parsing the body first using `JSON.parse(body)` and then log it.

Comment: it didnt work, i get this error `Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Have you tried setting the `encoding` property on your request options? The default encoding is `utf8`.

Comment: I tried to set `encoding ` to `null` but it didnt work

Comment: I just found my awnser! just add `gzip: true`